# How to declare a value type in CIL: `.class value` or just `.class`?

Tags: syntax, definition, cil, value-type, ilasm

I have taken a look at a C# `struct FooStruct` in [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx), and have seen the following:

[image]

ILDASM here displays two differing declarations:

- one starting with `.class` **`value`** `public` (rear window & front window's title bar)
- one starting with just `.class public` (front window)

And I wonder which syntax (if not both) is the correct one for declaring a value type? Is the `value` modifier strictly necessary, or optional, or a syntax error?

Comment: One thing to remember, ILASM is just an assembler of MSIL. Unlike byte code, it does offer a few short cuts without limiting expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Short answer:** Value type definitions only require `extends [mscorlib]System.ValueType`; the `value` attribute appears to be optional and has no apparent effect.

I assume that the CLI specification ([ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)) would be the best place to look for an authorative answer.

### MUST a value type definition include the `value` attribute?

Section II.10 deals with defining types. More specifically, subsection II.10.1.3 states:

> *The type semantic attributes specify whether an interface, class, or value type shall be defined.  … If [the `interface`] attribute is not present and the definition extends 
>   (directly or indirectly) `System.ValueType`, and the definition is not for `System.Enum`, a value type shall be defined (§II.13). Otherwise, a class shall be defined (§II.11).*

The `value` attribute is not mentioned at all in the whole section.

**Conclusion:** A correct value type definition does not have to include `value`. Deriving from `System.ValueType` is sufficient.

### MAY a value type definition include the `value` modifier?

The CLI standard also contains a grammar for ILASM (in section VI.C.3). According to that grammar, there exists a `value` attribute for `.class` type definitions. I additionally searched the standard for concrete value type definitions and found these examples:

- `.class public sequential ansi serializable sealed beforefieldinit System.Double extends System.ValueType …`
- `.class private sealed Rational extends [mscorlib]System.ValueType …`
- `.class` **`value`** `sealed public MyClass extends [mscorlib]System.ValueType …`

**Conclusion:** A `value` attribute may be included in a value type definition.

### And what does the `value` attribute MEAN?

I tried to compile these three IL type definitions into an assembly:

```
.class       public sealed … A extends [mscorlib]System.ValueType { … }
.class value public sealed … B extends [mscorlib]System.ValueType { … }
.class value public sealed … C extends [mscorlib]System.Object    { … }  // !!!
```

There was no compilation error, even though the `value` attribute is used in a reference type declaration (see last line). Looking at the resulting assembly using Visual Studio 2012's Object Browser reveals two value types (`struct`) `A` and `B`, and one reference type (`class`) `C`.

**Speculation:** The presence of the `value` attribute has no effect whatsoever on the type definition. It is only there as a potential aid for humans in spotting value type definitions.

Comment: In that case, it's not a great aid if it can be completely wrong both ways.

Answer (score 2):

This great [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596463) contains simple
answer: when you provide `extends` clause then `value` flag is ignored, but if you doesn't provide
`extends` and use `value` then ilasm will declare given type as value type.

In other words `value` was introduced as syntactic sugar, to quickly declare value type.